# This.state is 0 inside .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Iam trying to convert all selected item id's from a redux store into the item names and save it into state.

My problem is that the spread operator inside the setState function is equal to zero. Do I have to bind the context of the function to the class?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item_Name: []
    };
}




  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.Cart_Items.Id.map((item, i) => {
      if (item === "001") {
        // The problem is that this.state.item_Name is 0
        console.log(this.state.item_Name)
        this.setState({
          item_Name: [...this.state.item_Name, "Buddha"]
        });
      }
    })
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous and will batch updates.
Another thing, `.map` is returning an array, so just store the new array in a variable and pass it to `setState`.

P.S, you are checking for a condition inside `.map`. but `.map` should return the same number of members, add an `else` or just use `.filter` or `.reduce`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const nextState = this.props.Cart_Items.Id.map((item, i) => {
      if (item === "001") {
        return "Buddha"
      }
      // you need an else here because map should return the same number of members, or use .filter or .reduce
    })
    this.setState({item_name: nextstate});
  }
```

Comment: was this answers your question?